Is Leaflet.js with google tilelayer legal or not?
We are building traveling website and we are planning to use Maps API a lot. Because price per 1k request is high, we are investigating cheaper options. I noticed however conflicting articles about  Leaflet.js with google tilelayer. It looks like it's violating Google Maps terms but at the same time I see websites doing it so is there perhaps unofficial rule here? Can we use it until we reach some high usage and then Google will ping us to switch to paid API?
Initially we would love to avoid those high costs, find the product market fit and then switch to payments.

I‘m the Dev of OpenGuessr :)
I wasn‘t talking about the API for the map here (but the streetview API) and nor was I trying to brag, rather explaining the high costs, just to clarify.
Using leaflet + Google Tiles is violating the TOS as far as I‘m concerned, Google itself didn‘t seem very sure about that in their response but they did advise me to use the JavaScript Maps API as this other solution is not a documented API available via the Cloud Platform and therefore not TOS compliant.
For this reason, I am in the process of switching to the JS Maps API, just figuring out final contract details with a Google partner firm. I hope this answers your question.
Small edit:
But you are right, there are a lot of popular sites using this method. VirtualVacation, WorldGuessr or ChatGuessr would be some examples in this niche.

Can you share for how long were you able to avoid payments for Google APIs? Did they reach out or you? We would like to avoid those until we have a product market fit and enough users. On their website they mentioned "Volume discounts are available, starting at 20% off", so that would be nice.

I don‘t want to advise you to circumvent costs. Google did reach out to me. Please tell me more about your website and what API‘s you would need because I may know cheaper options.
